# How to formally prove that a line segment $[z,w]$ can be covered by overlapping disks?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let's say that $[z,w]$, i.e. the closed line segement between $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$ is of length less than $R$. How can I argue for the fact that the line segment can be covered by $5$ disks of radius $R/10$ with centres in $[z,w)$ (halfopen segment)?

Comment: Just write down the centres, e.g., points $1/10$, $3/10$ etc., of the way from $z$ to $w$.

Comment: @lordsharktheunkown can you elaborate?

Comment: You have 5 (open) disks of diameter $R/5$ to cover a segment of length $<R$. Do the math.

Comment: Are the disks open or closed? Open disks are just a little (really, _just_ a little) more complicated to place correctly.

Comment: @davidk Open disks.

Comment: Actually, looking at the answer, it's actually quite easy to place the disks even if they're open. You just have to keep track of which inequalities are sharp, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $[z, w] = \{(1-\lambda)z + \lambda w : \lambda \in [0,1]\}$. Consider the disks centered at:

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{10}\right)z + \frac1{10}w$$
$$\left(1 - \frac{3}{10}\right)z + \frac3{10}w$$
$$\left(1 - \frac{5}{10}\right)z + \frac5{10}w$$
$$\left(1 - \frac{7}{10}\right)z + \frac7{10}w$$
$$\left(1 - \frac{9}{10}\right)z + \frac9{10}w$$

Those disks cover $[z,w]$. Indeed, take an arbitrary $(1-\lambda)z + \lambda w$ for some $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

There exists $i \in \{0, 1, \ldots,9\}$ such that $$\frac{i}{10} \le \lambda \le \frac{i+1}{10}$$

Without loss of generality assume that $i$ is odd. Consider the disk centered at $\left(1 - \frac{i}{10}\right)z + \frac{i}{10}w$.

We have:

\begin{align}\left\|(1-\lambda)z + \lambda w - \left(1-\frac{i}{10}\right)z -
 \frac{i}{10} w\right\|&= \left\|\left(\frac{i}{10} -
 \lambda\right)z + \left(\lambda - \frac{i}{10}\right)w\right\|\\
&=\underbrace{\left(\lambda - \frac{i}{10}\right)}_{\le\frac{1}{10}}\underbrace{\|z-w\|}_{<R}\\
&< \frac{R}{10}
\end{align}

Therefore, $(1-\lambda)z + \lambda w$ is contained in the disk around $\left(1 - \frac{i}{10}\right)z + \frac{i}{10}w$.

If $i$ were even, we would consider the disk centered at $\left(1 - \frac{i+1}{10}\right)z + \frac{i+1}{10}w$.

We conclude that the disks cover $[z,w]$.

Comment: how do you exactly conclude the case where i is even?

Comment: @seht111 If $i$ is even, then $i+1$ is odd so just consider the disk around $\left(1 - \frac{i+1}{10}\right)z + \frac{i+1}{10}w$.
We have:
\begin{align}\left\|(1-\lambda)z + \lambda w - \left(1-\frac{i+1}{10}\right)z - \frac{i+1}{10} w\right\|&= \left\|\left(\frac{i+1}{10} -
 \lambda\right)z + \left(\lambda - \frac{i+1}{10}\right)w\right\|\\
&=\underbrace{\left(\frac{i+1}{10} - \lambda\right)}_{\le\frac{1}{10}}\underbrace{\|z-w\|}_{<R}\\
&< \frac{R}{10}
\end{align}
Therefore $(1-\lambda)z + \lambda w$ is contained in the disk around $\left(1 - \frac{i+1}{10}\right)z + \frac{i+1}{10}w$.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\frac{i+1}{10}-\lambda\leq 1/10$?. Also, can I show that the discs overlap somehow?

Thanks for the answers btw!

Comment: @seht111 We assumed $\frac{i}{10} \le \lambda \le \frac{i+1}{10}$ so $$\frac{i+1}{10} - \lambda \le \frac{i+1}{10} -\frac{i}{10} = \frac{1}{10}$$
Sure, the disks around $\left(1 - \frac{i}{10}\right)z + \frac{i}{10}w
$ and $\left(1 - \frac{i+2}{10}\right)z + \frac{i+2}{10}w
$ overlap for example at the point $\left(1 - \frac{i+1}{10}\right)z + \frac{i+1}{10}w
$.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated.